Player is not rotated when rotating camera
I have a Unity project in which I am using the New Input System to make my character controller.
I have my code divided into three parts:

InputManager.cs that is reading the input from the player and calling the functions to move the player in the Update function
PlayerMotor.cs that is managing the movement
PlayerLook.cs that is responsible for moving the camera.

I have a problem that when I am rotating the camera, the player is not rotating with it fast enough, and when pressing W key, instead of going forward, it goes to a different direction.
I am new to Unity so I have no idea how can I make this functionality and I would be glad if someone could help me with that.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;
    private PlayerMotor motor;
    private PlayerLook look;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
    void Awake()
    {
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        onFoot = playerInput.OnFoot;
        
        motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
        look = GetComponent<PlayerLook>();

        onFoot.Jump.performed += ctx => motor.Jump();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        motor.ProcessMove(onFoot.Movment.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        look.ProcessLook(onFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }
    
    private void OnEnable() {
        onFoot.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable() {
        onFoot.Disable();
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    private float xRotation = 0f;
    private float yRotation = 0f;

    public float xSensitivity = 1f;
    public float ySensitivity = 1f;
    
    public void ProcessLook(Vector2 input) {
        float mouseX = input.x;
        float mouseY = input.y;
        
        xRotation -= mouseY * ySensitivity;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -80f, 80f);
        yRotation += mouseX * xSensitivity;

        // Rotate camera on Y-axis for horizontal look
        cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);   

        // Rotate the player object (around its y-axis)
        transform.Rotate(mouseX * Time.deltaTime * xSensitivity * Vector3.up);
    }
}




You say

// Rotate camera on Y-axis for horizontal look


but in

cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);   


you apply both here X and Y rotation.
You should only apply the X one to the camera
// Rotate camera on Y-axis for horizontal look
cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);  

and then only apply the Y on the player itself.
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);

and then rather ensure that your calculations for yRotation contains the desired smoothing etc
